# How to make a menu like the one on Microsoft Windows website?

Tags: html, drupal, css, menu

I have a question to ask you if you can help me. 
I would like to have a menu like the one on the windows.microsoft.com website 
(http://awesomescreenshot.com/098jgh494) but on a Drupal website. Pretty much, two horizontal bars, the lower to be shown only when parent is clicked.

I tried several solutions but to no avail.

It will be great if you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Just setup the menu with 2 menu levels in backend.
Then use menu_block module via blocks or via panels.

That will result in the following HTML when only viewing level 1:

  ... (Menu level 1)

And the following when viewing a level 2 menu:

  ... (Menu level 1)

  ... (Menu level 2)

Finally, just style it with CSS.